# 'live' or 'lived' with did?

Tags: verbs, past-tense

I was looking at my neice's second grade note book in which was the question " Where did the four cows live? " but her mam corrected it to "Where did the four cows lived?"

I think it should be live as we use first form of verb with did. Am i wrong?